# Is there a way to delete all foreign entities when i delete a record using NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, cascading-deletes

I recently began using Fluent Nhibernate for my data layer and have come across an issue.  Whenever i want to delete a record that has multiple foreign key constraints, i have to create another class just to represent that database entity.  That means that for something like a User record, which has relationships with many other tables, i have to create something like 10 different classes that i will never use for any other purpose.  At least that is my understanding of how things work.

Is there a way for me to delete all of these records without having to map them.  For instance, using the User example, a User can have multiple roles, departments, email addresses, phone numbers, addresses, and so on.  I would like to delete all of these records, but not have to map all of them in Nhibernate classes.

Is there a property i can set on my UserMapping that would accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use magic. It's the best way to get a framework to guess your intent while you try to hide it. More information at http://hogwarts.ac.uk

Answer (score 1):

If those entities aren't mapped, NHibernate can't possibly know about them. But you could pick one of these alternatives:

- Set up [FK cascades at the database level](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=128) (if your database supports it)
- Use a database trigger to manually code the cascade (if your database supports triggers)
- Use a IPostDeleteEventListener (similar to a database trigger but at NHibernate level) to manually code the cascade.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was really hoping there would some kind of under-the-hood magic that would read the schema and cascade the delete where necessary, but yes i can see that being unrealistic.   I guess what i will have to do is create the necessary classes and only map the properties that i have to.